# How to modify this python code to make it run faster?

Tags: python, performance, dataframe

How to modify the code below to make it run faster? It currently takes 30 seconds to run from i = 0 to i = 75125.

```
for i in range(0, len(df.index)):  
     if i % 25 == 0:  
         df.iloc[i, 15] = df.iloc[i, 27]  
         df.iloc[i + 1, 15] = df.iloc[i, 26]  
         df.iloc[i + 2, 15] = df.iloc[i, 25]  
         df.iloc[i + 3, 15] = df.iloc[i, 24]  
         df.iloc[i + 4, 15] = df.iloc[i, 23]  
         df.iloc[i + 5, 15] = df.iloc[i, 22]  
         df.iloc[i + 6, 15] = df.iloc[i, 21]  
         df.iloc[i + 7, 15] = df.iloc[i, 20]  
         df.iloc[i + 8, 15] = df.iloc[i, 19]  
         df.iloc[i + 9, 15] = df.iloc[i, 18]  
         df.iloc[i + 10, 15] = df.iloc[i, 17]  
         df.iloc[i + 11, 15] = df.iloc[i, 16]  
         df.iloc[i + 12, 15] = df.iloc[i, 15]  
         df.iloc[i + 13, 15] = df.iloc[i, 28]   
         df.iloc[i + 14, 15] = df.iloc[i, 29]  
         df.iloc[i + 15, 15] = df.iloc[i, 30]  
         df.iloc[i + 16, 15] = df.iloc[i, 31]  
         df.iloc[i + 17, 15] = df.iloc[i, 32]  
         df.iloc[i + 18, 15] = df.iloc[i, 33]  
         df.iloc[i + 19, 15] = df.iloc[i, 34]  
         df.iloc[i + 20, 15] = df.iloc[i, 35]  
         df.iloc[i + 21, 15] = df.iloc[i, 36]  
         df.iloc[i + 22, 15] = df.iloc[i, 37]  
         df.iloc[i + 23, 15] = df.iloc[i, 38]  
         df.iloc[i + 24, 15] = df.iloc[i, 39]
```

Comment: Try doing `range(0, len(df.index), 25)` and not doing the `if` statement.

Comment: Without knowing more about the data in the dataframe or what the algorithm is trying to accomplish, it is quite hard to recommend anything.